# How to clear a cesium map before attempting to redraw points

Tags: javascript, html, cesiumjs

I am sending points to a cesium map and trying to make the points move from one location to the other. I am trying to clear the map before adding my points but what I have does not work.  What is the best way to clear the map of points,etc.
It seems like it would work but the only way I can sometimes see the correct points is to do browser refresh . Thanks

```
var viewer   = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', { infoBox : false });
var scene    = viewer.scene;
var points   = scene.primitives.add(new Cesium.PointPrimitiveCollection());
var entities = viewer.entities;
var entity = "";
```

...

```
entities.removeAll();
points.removeAll();
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete code sample that will reproduce the problem you're seeing?

Comment: have you tried calling scene.primitives.removeAll() ??

Answer (score 0):

I was experimenting with Cesium and here is how it works for me - 
(Note:Below is not the complete code but a sample for reference)

Am calling loadData at an interval of 10 secs and each time I am doing a `viewer.entities.removeAll();`

Sample Ref code :

```
function plotGeoPoints(){
  Cesium.loadJson(APIURL).then(function(data) {
  pdata = data;
  for ( var i = 0; i < pdata.length; i++){
          viewer.entities.add({
              position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(pdata[i].longitude, pdata[i].latitude),
              point : {
                  pixelSize : 5,
                  color : CESIUM.Color.RED,
                  outlineWidth:0
              }
      });
    }
  }
 }

function loadData(){
    viewer.entities.removeAll();
    plotGeoPoints();
 }
}

loadData();
intervalId = setInterval(loadData,10000);
```